# cuda & rdc & thrust in multiple shared objects results in SIGSEV in registerEntryFunction

Tags: cuda, cmake, thrust, .so

I'm trying to run relocatable-device-code in two shared libraries, both using cuda-thrust. Everything runs fine if I stop using thrust in kernel.cu, which is not an option.

edit: The program works too if rdc is disabled. Not an option for me either.

It compiles fine but stops with a segfault when run. gdb tells me this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000422cc8 in cudart::globalState::registerEntryFunction(void**, char const*, char*, char const*, int, uint3*, uint3*, dim3*, dim3*, int*) ()
(cuda-gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000422cc8 in cudart::globalState::registerEntryFunction(void**, char const*, char*, char const*, int, uint3*, uint3*, dim3*, dim3*, int*) ()
#1  0x000000000040876c in __cudaRegisterFunction ()
#2  0x0000000000402b58 in __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**) ()
#3  0x00007ffff75051a3 in __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary(__fatBinC_Wrapper_t const*, void (*)(void**), void*) ()
from /home/mindoms/rdctestmcsimple/libkernel.so
#4  0x00007ffff75050b1 in __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_66_tmpxft_00007a5f_00000000_16_cuda_device_runtime_    compute_52_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37 () from /home/user/rdctestmcsimple/libkernel.so
#5  0x000000000045285d in __libc_csu_init ()
#6  0x00007ffff65ea50f in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Here is my stripped down example (using cmake) that shows the error.

main.cpp:

```
#include "kernel.cuh"
#include "kernel2.cuh"

int main(){
  Kernel k;
  k.callKernel();

  Kernel2 k2;
  k2.callKernel2();
}
```

kernel.cuh:

```
#ifndef __KERNEL_CUH__
#define __KERNEL_CUH__
  class Kernel{
  public:
    void callKernel();
  };
#endif
```

kernel.cu:

```
#include "kernel.cuh"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

__global__
void thekernel(int *data){
  if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    printf("the kernel says hello\n");

  data[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x * 2;
}

void Kernel::callKernel(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> D2;
  D2.resize(11);
  int * raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&D2[0]);

  printf("Kernel::callKernel called\n");
  thekernel <<< 1, 10 >>> (raw_ptr);

  cudaThreadSynchronize();
  cudaError_t code = cudaGetLastError();
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    std::cout << "Cuda error: " << cudaGetErrorString(code) << " after callKernel!" << std::endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < D2.size(); i++)
  std::cout << "Kernel D[" << i << "]=" << D2[i] << std::endl;
}
```

kernel2.cuh:

```
#ifndef __KERNEL2_CUH__
#define __KERNEL2_CUH__
  class Kernel2{
  public:
    void callKernel2();
  };
#endif
```

kernel2.cu

```
#include "kernel2.cuh"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

__global__
void thekernel2(int *data2){
  if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    printf("the kernel2 says hello\n");

  data2[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x * 2;
}

void Kernel2::callKernel2(){
  thrust::device_vector<int> D;
  D.resize(11);
  int * raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&D[0]);
  printf("Kernel2::callKernel2 called\n");
  thekernel2 <<< 1, 10 >>> (raw_ptr);

  cudaThreadSynchronize();
  cudaError_t code = cudaGetLastError();
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    std::cout << "Cuda error: " << cudaGetErrorString(code) << " after callKernel2!" << std::endl;
}

  for (int i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
  std::cout << "Kernel2 D[" << i << "]=" << D[i] << std::endl;
}
```

The cmake file below was used originally, but I get the same problem when I compile "by hand":

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc kernel2.cu 
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -shared -Xcompiler -fPIC kernel2.o -o libkernel2.so
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc kernel.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -shared -Xcompiler -fPIC kernel.o -o libkernel.so
g++ -o main main.cpp libkernel.so libkernel2.so -L/opt/cuda/current/lib64
```

Adding `-cudart shared` to every nvcc call as suggested somewhere results in a different error:

```
warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaFuncGetAttributes returned (0x8)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  function_attributes(): after cudaFuncGetAttributes: invalid device function

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x000000313c432625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(cuda-gdb) bt
#0  0x000000313c432625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000313c433e05 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000031430bea7d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000031430bcbd6 in std::set_unexpected(void (*)()) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00000031430bcc03 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00000031430bcc86 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7d600eb in thrust::detail::vector_base<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> >::append(unsigned long) () from ./libkernel.so
#7  0x00007ffff7d5f740 in thrust::detail::vector_base<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> >::resize(unsigned long) () from ./libkernel.so
#8  0x00007ffff7d5b19a in Kernel::callKernel() () from ./libkernel.so
#9  0x00000000004006f8 in main ()
```

CMakeLists.txt: Please adjust to your environment

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)

project(Cuda-project)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/cuda" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

SET(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR "/opt/cuda/current")

SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}  -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
link_directories(${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/lib64)

set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -Xcompiler -fPIC)

CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(kernel
  kernel.cu
  )

CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(kernel2
  kernel2.cu
)

cuda_add_executable(rdctest main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(rdctest kernel kernel2 cudadevrt)
```

About my system:

```
Fedora 23 
kernel: 4.4.2-301.fc23.x86_64
Nvidia Driver: 361.28 
Nvidia Toolkit: 7.5.18
g++: g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2)
```

Reproduced on:

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Kernel: 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64
Nvidia Driver: 352.55
Nvidia Toolkit: 7.5.18
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
glibc 2.12
cmake to 3.5
```

Comment: fedora 23 and g++ 5.3.1 is [not an officially supported environment for CUDA 7.5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the input. I reproduced the problem on a supported system and updated the question.

Comment: related discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/LJ8vPiY6-78).

Comment: This appears to have exposed a bug in the CUDA executable packaging system.  I have filed a bug internally at NVIDIA which is under review.  Until that review is complete, I won't be able to respond to requests for additional information or status.  The nature of the bug here appears to be quite fragile, so apart from making such suggestions as "don't use thrust" or "don't use relocatable device code" or "don't use multiple shared objects" I'm unable to offer workaround suggestions. If possible, I will revisit the question when I have further information.

Comment: To be clear, I believe that the general methodology expressed here *should* work, and that is demonstrable with a slight change to the posted code, but it is "fragile" and not suitable as a workaround suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this has something to do with what cuda runtime is used: shared or static.

I slightly modified your example: Instead of building two shared libraries and linking them to the executable individually, I create two static libraries that are linked together to one shared library, and that one is linked to the executable.

Also, here is an updated CMake file that uses the new (>= 3.8) native CUDA language support.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project (CudaSharedThrust CXX CUDA)

string(APPEND CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS " -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61")

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
endif()

add_library(kernel STATIC kernel.cu)
set_target_properties(kernel PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

add_library(kernel2 STATIC kernel2.cu)
set_target_properties(kernel2  PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

add_library(allkernels empty.cu) # empty.cu is an empty file
set_target_properties(allkernels PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(allkernels kernel kernel2)


add_executable(rdctest main.cpp)
set_target_properties(rdctest PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(rdctest allkernels)
```

Building this without any CMake flags (static build), the build succeeds and the program works.

Building with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`, the program compiles, but it crashes with the same error is yours.

Building with

```
cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS:STRING="--cudart shared"
```

compiles, and actually makes it run! So for some reason, the shared CUDA runtime is required for this sort of thing.

Also note that the step from 2 SO's -> 2 Static Libs in 1 SO was necessary, because otherwise the program would crash with a `hrust::system::system_error`.

This, however is expected because NVCC actually ignores shared object files during device linking: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#libraries