# CUDA separable compilation + shared libraries -> Invalid device function / segfault

Tags: c++, cuda, segmentation-fault, nvcc

I'm trying to use CUDA separable compilation in my project. The project is composed of a binary that depends on a few shared libraries (all built in the same build system). These shared libraries in turn use common CUDA code. When running the binary, I get a segfault similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526858/cuda-rdc-thrust-in-multiple-shared-objects-results-in-sigsev-in-registerentr). When I create a minimal example, I get "invalid device function" error instead. **If I turn the shared libraries into static libraries, the error goes away**. Unfortunately I don't have control over this and need to make it work with shared libraries.

I have seen a couple similar posts here in SO, but they use CMake and the solutions usually involve changing libraries from shared to static, which I can't do in my project. I have double-checked that I'm running the code on the right GPU (and indeed it works if I do some changes, see below), so that's not the issue.

I believe I'm missing something when doing CUDA separable compilation, device linking or creating shared libraries.

Below is a fully reproducible minimal example of the problem:

```cpp
// common.h
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

__device__ int common();

#endif
```

```cpp
// common.cu
#include "common.h"

__device__ int common()
{
    return 123;
}
```

```cpp
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
void runA();

#endif
```

```cpp
// a.cu
#include "a.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "common.h"

__global__ void kernelA()
{
    printf("Running A: %d\n", 456 + common());
}

void runA()
{
    kernelA<<<1,1>>>();
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError()) << std::endl;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

```cpp
// b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
void runB();

#endif
```

```cpp
// b.cu
#include "b.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "common.h"

__global__ void kernelB()
{
    printf("Running B: %d\n", 321 + common());
}

void runB()
{
    kernelB<<<1,1>>>();
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError()) << std::endl;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    runA();
    runB();
}
```

So basically a binary depending on 2 shared libraries A and B, both of which utilize the `common()` device function.

This is my build/test script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail

CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda-10.2
NVCC=$CUDA_ROOT/bin/nvcc
CC=/usr/bin/g++
GENCODE="arch=compute_75,code=sm_75"

# Clean previous build
rm -f *.o *.so main

# Compile relocatable CUDA code
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dc -Xcompiler -fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden common.cu -o common.cu.o
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dc -Xcompiler -fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden      a.cu -o      a.cu.o
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dc -Xcompiler -fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden      b.cu -o      b.cu.o

# Build shared library A
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dlink common.cu.o a.cu.o -o a.dlink.o
$CC -shared common.cu.o a.cu.o a.dlink.o -L$CUDA_ROOT/lib64 -lcudart -o liba.so

# Build shared library B
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dlink common.cu.o b.cu.o -o b.dlink.o
$CC -shared common.cu.o b.cu.o b.dlink.o -L$CUDA_ROOT/lib64 -lcudart -o libb.so

# Build final executable
$CC main.cpp -L. -la -lb -o main

# Run it
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

Running it I get:

```
invalid device function
invalid device function
```

After some trial and error, I notice the problem is solved by:

- Not linking `common.cu.o` in either library when device linking (obviously I need to make either library no longer use the `common()` function.
- Making A and B static libraries.
- Combining A and B into one single shared library.

Unfortunately I cannot apply these solutions in my project. Why is it a problem to have 2 shared libraries? I've read about the "device linker ignoring shared libraries", but in this case it's the host linker creating the shared library, not the device linker, so I'm hoping that's OK?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as shared *device* libraries. You have to use static device side linkage, whether you do it at build time or do it at runtime. That is non-negotiable.

Comment: I'm not creating a shared device library, the entrypoints to the library a regular C++ functions that call CUDA code. Otherwise, how is CuDNN, TensoRT, etc implemented? They are shared libraries that inside call CUDA code. A shared device library would be a .so file that provides some `__device__` function to be imported somewhere else. That's not what I'm doing here. I want to link all CUDA functions statically inside each shared library.

Comment: @user1011113: But you effectively are, because you have device code dependence between two dynamically linked host libraries. That can never work. And that is what libraries like CUDNN and CUBLAS don't do

Comment: @talonmies Both shared libraries use the same common code, yes, but they are statically linked independently of each other. Also, i make sure to use '-fvisibility=hidden' to prevent exporting symbols - wouldn't that lead to each library just having their own static copy of the 'common ()' function? Perhaps as Robert says having duplicate symbols like this is not possible for whatever reason, like the runtime linker doesn't know what to do with that. I asked in the Nvidia forums, let's see what they say! Thanks!

Comment: Playing a bit more, I tried now to create only 1 shared library, but still perform 2 device linking steps (a.dlink.o, b.dlink.o). If I try to link those 2 together into one shared library, I get:

multiple definition of `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_41_tmpxft_00001022_00000000_6_common_cpp1_ii_e5ca4d49'

So I guess this goes unnoticed if I link the libraries separately. So the problem must be the runtime linker not knowing what to do with these duplicated symbols? In regular C++ it will just pick one, and shouldn't matter if both are identical (like it is here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with Nvidia, I finally found the solution to the problem:

**Add `-Xcompiler -fvisibility=hidden` to each of the `dlink` commands**

```sh
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dlink -Xcompiler -fvisibility=hidden common.cu.o a.cu.o -o a.dlink.o
$NVCC -gencode=$GENCODE -dlink -Xcompiler -fvisibility=hidden common.cu.o b.cu.o -o b.dlink.o
```

The original issue was that, indeed, both `liba.so` and `libb.so` were exporting the same symbol publicly  (`__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_41_tmpxft_00000c46_00000000_6_common_cpp1_ii_e5ca4d49`), which of course leads to conflict. Adding `-fvisibility=hidden` to the `dlink` command makes it a private symbol in each library instead, so there's no more conflicts.

Thanks for the help!